# Cakephp 3 HTTP Basic Authentication login issue

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0, basic-authentication

I am using basic authentication in my project to access Api. In ApiController, I added below code in beforeFilter:

```
   $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
       'Basic' => [
           'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'api_key'],
           'userModel' => 'Users'
       ]
   ]);
```

So from chrome postman application, I am sending post request with basic auth credentials. for example like below:
[image]

So when I send a request, I get unauthorized error back.

Comment: Have you done the basic checks that are suggested in the other questions about login problems that can be found here on SO? Checked the column type/length, ensured that the passwords are really stored hashed, debugged the queries that are being issued (Do they find anything at all? If there's actually something being found, what exactly is it, does it match the value in the DB?), ensured that hashes are generally being stored correctly when creating a new user, etc...

Comment: @ndm, I have done initial troubleshooting to check how passwords are stored in the DB. I am able to create new api key in api_key field in Users table. by following this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-api-keys-for-basic-authentication).

Comment: What the docs suggest there doesn't make much sense without further logic, as you cannot simply exchange the password, which is by default tested with the configured password hasher (BCRYPT), for a token which by default uses a different hashing algorithm (SHA1). The docs need to be fixed, you may want to [**create an issue**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues) over at GitHub.

Comment: If the authentication adapter would _not_ use the password hasher for comparison, then this would make authenticating API requests less secure than normal authentication, as you are not only _transmitting_ the "password" (token) in plain text, you are even _storing_ it in plain text.

In order for the linked example to actually work as shown, the token would need to be hashed with the password hasher used by the authentication adapter, similar to [**how it's done with passwords**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords).

Answer (score 0):

you are sending a post request with a 'password' field

Your application is expecting a 'api_key' field that would contain the password.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But in my controller, I using password as a field and I am inserting api_key values in password field. `'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'api_key']`. Shouldn't BasicAuthenticate from cakephp take care of rest to check api_key field in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this one script in your model entity.

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;


        protected function _setPassword($password)
        {
            if (strlen($password) > 0) {
                return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
            }
        }
```

Put this one in Model/Entity/User.php